# How to get regression output in R ignoring one factor level in data?

Tags: r, dplyr, lm, purrr

I am running a regression on the nested data with factor variables. If one grouped data has one factor level, the regression fails and throws the error "contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels". For eg:

```
data <- mtcars %>% mutate(am = if_else(carb==1, 1,am),
                          am=as.factor(am))

data_carb <- data %>%
  group_by(carb) %>% 
  nest()

X <- c("cyl", "disp", "hp" , "drat", "wt", "qsec", "vs", "am", "gear")
Y <- "mpg"

generic_model <- function(df) {
  lm(reformulate(X, Y), data = df)
}

modelondata <-  data_carb %>% 
  mutate(model = data %>% map(generic_model),
         coeff  = model %>% map(broom::tidy)) %>% 
  unnest(coeff, .drop = TRUE)
```

How can I keep the variable as factor and get the output for atleast those grouped data for which the factor levels are more than 1 i.e for carb!=1?

In my real data, I have many factor variables with dozens of levels and the regression fails even if one of the grouped data has constant factor level. So, I don't want to drop the variables as I would lose insights into the other grouped data as well.

Comment: `tryCatch(lm(...))` ?

Comment: Can you advise, how I can do that in the code?

Comment: `tryCatch(lm(reformulate(X, Y), data = df), error = function(e) NULL)` everything else the same.. or `function(e) NA` if you want to keep the grouping levels

Comment: @rawr: It worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What if you created a function to drop columns with "fixed" factors

```
drop_fixed_factors <- function(x) {
  x %>% keep(~!is.factor(.x) | length(unique(.x))>2)
}
```

Then did something like this

```
generic_model <- function(df) {
  good_data <- df[X] %>% drop_fixed_factors()
  lm(reformulate(names(good_data), Y), data = df)
}
```

Then you can keep only the columns that have variability.

Comment: I can do that, but I guess, I will lose the coefficients on that part of the grouped/nested data that has variability.

Comment: Well, you are applying this to just the grouped data so you will just get different subsets for each group. `modelondata %>% group_by(carb) %>%  count()`

Comment: I am getting the same error on my actual data. Isn't !is.factor(.x) dropping all the factor variables?

Comment: Also, won't NA produce one additional level in factor variables? How can I deal with that?